# Are there any CSS Preprocessor GUI Applications that can concatenate files?

Tags: css

I recently started looking into using SASS along with Koala in order to make my CSS more efficient.  I like the idea of using variables to maintain consistent and easy to remember stylings, but I was wondering if any of the applications like Koala/CodeKit have the ability to concatenate the CSS upon compilation of the SASS -> CSS.  This way I can write my SASS files in a modular way, but then only have to worry about a single, master CSS file when it comes to production and trying to reduce my GET requests.

What options do I have?

Thanks

Comment: I usually just use grunt or gulp to compile and then concatenate.

Comment: sass can do this. you can tell your grunt file to listen on any scss file and compile from a main scss file that just uses @import to pull in all the individual files. You can minify as well. A little google searching would cover this

Comment: FYI both Koala and CodeKit concatenate and minify. Concatenation is handled by @import declarations (see http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-5) and minification is configured within the apps.

Comment: I wasn't sure what to Google exactly.. I tried googling like "CSS preprocessor concatenate files"..etc and found nothing. I know of tools like grunt and gulp, just never used them because they are node based and we don't use node for anything

Comment: @Cue does import actually concatenate?? Would using `@import` actually limit the GET requests to 1?`

Comment: Well, @import while using grunt would do so if configured correctly. There's no real reason to avoid node unless you are much more familiar with your tools and prefer it otherwise. node/grunt have improved development enormously for me and I'm one of those people who don't like changing from comfort. It was worth the minor learning curve and minimal requirements.

Comment: @MattHintzke Yes the `@import` will simply inherit another sass file into the file that declares it. Concatenation takes place when the file is compiled in Koala/CodeKit/Grunt/gulp etc.

Comment: Oh cool, didn't know the concatenation happened at that step. Ok I will look into doing that with Koala then. Thanks